# Place chapter title between 2 thick lines

Tags: chapters, titles, rules, line

I'm new to Latex, and I've been trying to style my chapter title.
This is similar to what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I've been googling around, checking the Latex Wikibook (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) and searching on this forum, but all I could produce so far is this:

[image]

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\bfseries\Huge}
{}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[3pt]\thechapter\titlerule[3pt]}
```

I can't figure out how to move the "Introduction" next to the chapter number (between the 2 lines). Also I couldn't figure out how to raise both lines from sitting on the baseline of the text.

*P.S. The above code sits inside my .sty file (if it matters).*

Any guidance please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Not quite sure of what you want. Only the chapter number between two thick rules , or \chaptername+chapter number, and the chapter title on another line below?

Comment: I want the chapter number and the chapter title next to each other, both between 2 thick rules (I'm not interested in the \chaptername - which as far as I understood only prints the word 'Chapter'). The outcome should look something like "----- 1. Introduction ------"

Comment: By the way, I'm using the "report" documentclass, if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `xhfill` package, and `titlesec` with option `[explicit]`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\filcenter\bfseries\Huge}
{\xrfill[0.4ex]{3pt}\ \thechapter.}
{0.3em}
{#1\ \xrfill[0.4ex]{3pt}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked :)
How come "#1" holds the chapter title? Is it part of a bigger function that I could look up to understand it?

Comment: It is explained in the documentation – it's specific to the èxplicit` option, which I had to use to make the formatting with a rule after the title work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look